CocoaMQTT Server connection refused
Cannot connect with cocoamqtt 5.0, it says connection refused when using in Xcode, below is code :-
 func buildMQTTConnection() {
    ///MQTT 5.0
    let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
//  let mqtt5 = CocoaMQTT5(clientID: clientID, host: "broker.hivemq.com", port: 1883)
    
    let mqtt5 = CocoaMQTT5(clientID: clientID, host: "8dbc6815c7824b0482d7ae0439514faa.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud", port: 8883)
    
    let connectProperties = MqttConnectProperties()
    connectProperties.topicAliasMaximum = 0
    connectProperties.sessionExpiryInterval = 0
    connectProperties.receiveMaximum = 100
    connectProperties.maximumPacketSize = 500
    mqtt5.connectProperties = connectProperties
    
    /// SSL Configuration
    let clientCertArray = getClientCertFromP12File(certName: "certificate", certPassword: "gurpal")
    var sslSettings: [String: NSObject] = [:]
    sslSettings[kCFStreamSSLCertificates as String] = clientCertArray
    mqtt5.allowUntrustCACertificate = true
    mqtt5.enableSSL = true
    mqtt5.sslSettings = sslSettings
    
    
    mqtt5.username = "gurpal"
    mqtt5.password = "#Gurpal25"
    mqtt5.willMessage = CocoaMQTT5Message(topic: "/will", string: "dieout")
    mqtt5.delegate = self
    mqtt5.keepAlive = 60
    let connectionStatus = mqtt5.connect()
    print(connectionStatus)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        self.connStatusLbl.text = "\(mqtt5.connState.description)"
    }
    }

connection refused when trying to connect.
tried connecting cocoamqtt but it says connection refused, might be due to ssl, any help is appreciated.

I suspect that your client cannot establish TLS connection to the broker because your certificate is invalid. Where did you get this certificate from? Did you try removing this from your code?
    /// SSL Configuration
    let clientCertArray = getClientCertFromP12File(certName: "certificate", certPassword: "gurpal")
    var sslSettings: [String: NSObject] = [:]
    sslSettings[kCFStreamSSLCertificates as String] = clientCertArray

